# How to get full SSL certificates chain for specified site using Python SSL and OpenSSL

Tags: python, ssl, networking, ssl-certificate, pyopenssl

I am doing research on the requirements for using untrusted root certificates on the Internet and I am having some problems with SSL chain detection.

Now I detect specified certificates with this function:

```
def _get_root_cert(link: str):
    cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((link.split('//')[1], 443))
    x509 = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert.encode())
    return x509.get_issuer().get_components()[2][1].decode()
```

This code works fine, but for some sites (like [this](https://mintrans.ryazan.gov.ru))  I got No-Sni certificate name instead of `Russian Trusted CA`. So now I need to get the full certificate chain, but I have some problems.

[image: SSL chain example]

I've tried to get chain with this code, but it's not working as expected. Can anyone help me?

My experiments with chain detection:

```
import socket
import ssl
import base64
import binascii

hostname: str = 'https://mintrans.ryazan.gov.ru'

# Set up a socket connection to the site
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as sock:
        # Get the certificate chain
        cert_chain = sock.getpeercert(True)

# cert_chain_b64 = base64.b64encode(cert_chain).decode('utf-8')
# cert_chain_bytes = binascii.a2b_base64(cert_chain_b64)
# cert_chain_text = cert_chain_bytes.decode('utf-8')

cert_chain_text = None

try:
    cert_chain_text = cert_chain.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    pass

if cert_chain_text is None:
    try:
        cert_chain_text = cert_chain.decode('latin-1')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass

if cert_chain_text is None:
    try:
        cert_chain_text = cert_chain.decode('windows-1252')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass

if cert_chain_text is None:
    # Handle the error if none of the encodings work
    print('Unable to decode certificate chain')

print(cert_chain_text)
```

Comment: None of what you've tried is about getting the certificate **chain**,  but you only ask for the server certificate. Even `ssl.get_server_certificate` which you claim works for most sites will only return the server certificate, not the chain. That's why I assume that you actually only want to get the server certificate, contrary to what you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I don't know how to proceed with python but it's quiete easy with openssl :

```
echo Q |openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect google.com:443
```

Which result in :

```
verify depth is 5
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.google.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN = *.google.com

issuer=C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 6780 bytes and written 382 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

So in python if you can call a system command from the shell of the machine, you can use the previous command

Please also note the '-verify' value which is the depth of the chain.
For big chains with lots of intermediate, you can upgrade this number to 10 or 15.

For your special case with python maybe you can do something like :

```
import subprocess
cmd_str = "echo Q |openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 15 -connect google.com:443"
subprocess.run(cmd_str, shell=True)
```

PS : As suggested by @SteffenUllrich, if you're using an old version of openssl, you should add to the prevuious command the servername, for example in your use case :

```
-servername mintrans.ryazan.gov.ru
```

The whole command will be :

```
echo Q |openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 15 -connect mintrans.ryazan.gov.ru:443 -servername mintrans.ryazan.gov.ru
```

This is not necessary with :

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

Hope it could help

Comment: Yep, good solution, thanks. But this shell pipe doesn't solve the problem. If I run a command like this `echo Q |openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 15 -connect mintrans.ryazan.gov.ru:443` I only get a No-Sni certificate, although I can get the full chain in the browser that include Russian Trusteed CA and Sub CA. Do you have any idea how to fix this?
Command output [here](https://pastebin.com/AMEu8Utc)

Comment: @sigseg5: you seem to use an older version of openssl which does not set SNI by default. In this case you would need to add  `-servername mintrans.ryazan.gov.ru` to the arguments.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Thanks for comment, I've just update the answer with this precision.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I use `LibreSSL 3.3.6` on my Mac, thx for answer!